# UITableViewCell with checkbox repeating while scrolling

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview, checkbox

I'm using a UITableView witha custom cell (xib). Each cell are lables and a checkbox (UIButton).

I have 2 sections and 4 cells in each section. If I check the first cell of the first section, the forst cell of the second section will be check as well and I don't want. The problem: dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier.

I want to hold my cell identifier static.

How can I fix this ?

Here is the initializing of my array (for the content of my cells):

```
for(int i=0; i<NUMBER_OF_CELL; i++){

    Account *model = [[Account alloc]init];

    [model setAccountName:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Account %d",i]];
    [model setAccountNumber:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Number %d",i]];

    [_accountArray addObject:model];

}
```

Setting the content:

```
[[cell accountLabel] setText:_model.accountName];
[[cell accountNumberLabel] setText:_model.accountNumber];
```

***EDIT:***

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    _model = [_accountArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    AccountCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        NSArray *topLevelObjects = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"AccountCell" owner:self options:nil];
        cell = [topLevelObjects objectAtIndex:0];
    }
    // configure cell 
    [cell setSelectionStyle:UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone];

    [[cell accountLabel] setText:_model.accountName];
    [[cell accountNumberLabel] setText:_model.accountNumber];
    // checkbox ? 

    if(cell.isChecked){

        NSLog(@"Checked");
    }else{
        NSLog(@"No checked");
    }

    return cell;
}
```

In an other class, I check if the checkbox is checked or not:

```
- (IBAction)checkbox:(id)sender {

    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [(UITableView *)self.superview indexPathForCell: self];

    if(self.isChecked == NO)
    {
        self.isChecked = YES;
        [_checkbox setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"checkbox_checked.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];        
    }
    else{
        self.isChecked = NO;
        [_checkbox setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"checkbox.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    }

}
```

How can I distinguish each cell to avoid repeating checking ?

Thank you so much!
Best regards,

Comment: put code od cellforrowAtindexpath method

Answer (score 1):

You need to write following method in AccountCell.h/AccountCell.m

```
- (void)resetCell {

    //Reset Your cell content to default. So that you can reuse the cell.
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [(UITableView *)self.superview indexPathForCell: self];


        self.isChecked = NO;
        [_checkbox setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"checkbox.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

    //other resettings...
}
```

And then you can call this method from (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath as follows

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    _model = [_accountArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    AccountCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];


    if (cell == nil) {
        NSArray *topLevelObjects = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"AccountCell" owner:self options:nil];
        cell = [topLevelObjects objectAtIndex:0];
    }
    // configure cell 
    [cell setSelectionStyle:UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone];

    //reset your cell's content.
    [cell resetCell];

    //perform your task below
    [[cell accountLabel] setText:_model.accountName];
    [[cell accountNumberLabel] setText:_model.accountNumber];
    // checkbox ? 

    if(cell.isChecked){

        NSLog(@"Checked");
    }else{
        NSLog(@"No checked");
    }

    return cell;
}
```

Hope this helps.

Thanks.

Comment: Yes, It works but if the cell with checkbox checked is not visible (after scrolling), the checkbox checked earlier is unchecked :/

Comment: Whenever cell goes offscreen and it comes back on the screen, we are resetting the cell's display using resetCell (this is the default display of the cell which contains no value). After resetting it is our responsibility to marke the checkbox as checked. I mean you have to maintain the status of all the rows in an array (or any type you are using) and when cellForRowAtIndexPath gets called, you have to look into this array for status for that particular cell and update the contents of the cell programatically (In your case check the checkbox programatically)

Answer (score 0):

I think you'd be best using the selected state for the button to track whether it is checked. It looks like you've created an "AccountCell" class, so you should be able to simply have an outlet for the checkbox in the AccountCell class, such as:

```
@interface AccountCell : UITableViewCell
...
@property IBOutlet UIButton *checkBox;
```

Now, you can set the normal/checked images for the button in the AccountCell's viewDidLoad method (since this doesn't need to be done every time state changes):

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [_checkBox setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:"checkbox.png" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [_checkBox setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:"checkbox_checked.png" forState:UIControlStateSelected];
}
```

In your cellForRowAtIndex path you can make sure the checkbox is cleared for the returned cell by using:

```
cell.checkBox.selected = NO;
```

Then in the 'action' code for the checkbox you can use the following to switch the checkbox on and off:

```
self.selected = !self.selected;
```

Comment: Yes, I understand the concept, but I don't know how to implement it :/

Comment: Edited with new better answer that is more efficient, and should resolve your issue